# React find all components with class, update components state or props from outside. Modal with overlay

Tags: javascript, html, dom, reactjs, modal-dialog

I am trying to implement a modal with overlay. Modals can be nested, it is possible to open one modal from another. Overlay background should be stackable (should not make view behind darker with every new modal).

To add modal to document I use react-portal.

I can make every modal active or inactive with manipulating dom nodes:

```
class Modal extends React.Component {
componentDidMount() {
    const previousModal = findDOMNode(this).previousSibling
    if (previousModal) {
        previousModal.className = "modal inactive"
    }

}
componentWillUnmount() {
    const previousModal = findDOMNode(this).previousSibling
    if (previousModal) {
        previousModal.className = "modal"
    }
}
render() {
    return (
        <div className="modal">Model</div>
    );
}
```

}

```
<div>
<div class="modal inactive" data-reactid="2">Model</div>
<div class="modal inactive" data-reactid="3">Model</div>
<div class="modal" data-reactid="4">Model</div>
</div>
```

It feels like it is not correct solution. So I am looking for any ideas.

Comment: What specific question are you trying to have answered?

While this code can certainly work, it is probably better to use something like Flux or a Controller model to update each modal's state, so that they will rerender using the React API, instead of the DOM API.

Answer (score 0):

The best abstraction I can think of this is using state (either flux, redux, mobx or your own custom solution), since I have more experience with redux, here is how I would do it.

I would have a reducer, with a `modalCount` property, this would serve as a counter, every time you open a modal you increase the property by 1, when you close a modal you reduce the property by 1, then, somewhere in the root of your app I would place an overlay component that darkens the the view behind the modal, set the display css property (or better yet, return null) when this `modalCount` property is 0.

This, has two nice benefits, your code gets simpler per modal, they do not mess with the properties and displays of other components, and second, you are now abstracting this state into the app state and not relying on the DOM but actually on react lifecycle of your components.